# Split alternating values in a numeric vector into columns of a data-frame in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called data, which contains a column of numeric vectors called "time."  Each row is its own vector.

```
>data[1, ]$time
3000 3000 2991 2961 2958 2947 2925 2836 2890

>str(data$time)
$ time             :List of 20
..$ : num  3000 3000 2991 2961 2958 ...
```

I want to convert each row value the time column into a dataframe such that every odd index value is in a column of the dataframe called "odd" and every even index value is in a column called "even."

Here is a dummy example of how I may do that:

```
test <- c(3000,3000,2991,2961,2958,2947)
test <- data.frame(test)
odd <- test[ c(TRUE,FALSE), ] 
even <- test[ !c(TRUE,FALSE), ]
finalData <- data.frame(odd = odd, even = even )
```

The resulting output is now:

```
> finalData
   odd even
1 3000 3000
2 2991 2961
3 2958 2947
```

I just can't figure out how to do this process row-by-row with the real dataframe above.  I want to replace the time column in the above dataframe with a dataframe containing two odd and even columns. Is this clear?

Comment: So `data$time <- data.frame(split(data$time, c("odd", "even")))` ?  This generates an error ` replacement has 10 rows, data has 20`

Comment: Your exact data structure is not very clear. It would be easier if you provide it via a `dput`-

Comment: Why is `3000` in the `odd` and `even` columns?

Comment: It's not based on the number, it's based upon the index value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your data looks something like this?

```
time <- list(1:4, 1:6, 1:3)
data <- data.frame(cbind(time), dd=1:3)

data
#               time dd
# 1       1, 2, 3, 4  1
# 2 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6  2
# 3          1, 2, 3  3
```

In which case something like this should do

```
lapply(data$time, function(x) {
    odd <- seq_along(x) %% 2 == 1
    o <- x[odd]
    e <- x[!odd]
    length(e) <- length(o)
    data.frame(o, e)
    })

# [[1]]
#   o e
# 1 1 2
# 2 3 4

# [[2]]
#   o e
# 1 1 2
# 2 3 4
# 3 5 6

# [[3]]
#   o  e
# 1 1  2
# 2 3 NA
```

Do notice that this requires there to be an equal number of odd and even values in each vector. If you can't guarantee that you'd need to either pad with NA or store in lists.

Comment: two things: (1) I need odd and even INDEX values, not odd and even numbers. (2) I need the resulting output to be to be a new column which is a dataframe.  So data$time2 should be a data.frame containing the odd and even indices

Comment: @Parseltongue: Better? The output already is data.frames, they're just stored in a list.

Comment: thank you so much for your help!  I'm still getting the error: `Error in data.frame(o = x[odd], e = x[!odd]) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 57, 56` I assume this means I need to pad, but not sure how to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: As I mentioned, if the columns are of unequal length you either need to pad with NA or save as list.

Comment: Right, but I'm not sure how to pad with NAs.  Sorry, I'm new to this

Comment: There. It's the `length()` bit that does it. We can do it like that because we know that the odd one will never be the shortest.

Comment: This is so clever.  And coercing the length of one of the objects automatically adds the NAs?

Comment: Yup. I don't know if it's by design or accident, but it's a very useful trick.